# XSL-FO dynamic table-width with page-breaks and dynamic content

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I try to create a dynamic width of table-cells.
The table needs more than one page.

I tried

```
<fo:table inline-progression-dimension="auto" table-layout="auto">
```

and it solve the problem if the table is just on one page.

But if the content of an table-cell on the first page is for example "Figure 1" and on the content of a other table-cell (from the same table) on the second page is "Figure 2000" the width of the table-cell is just as wide as nesessary for the "Figure 1".

Is there any possiblity that the width for "Figure 2000" is considered on the first page of the table.

I am using Antenna House V6.1.

Comment: What is 'Figure 2000'?  Are you referring to the text 'Figure 2000' or are you talking about a graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many rows are in your table?  It can take a lot of resources to determine the best possible column widths for a large table, so AH Formatter defaults to considering the first 100 table rows. See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-tech.html#table-auto-layout and https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-optset.html#table-auto-layout-limit.

If you use `table-auto-layout-limit="0"` in your Option Setting File, then AH Formatter will consider all of the rows in the table.